# AngularJS - fire a function once after all directives with a certain name have rendered

Tags: angularjs

**Background**
Hi, let's say I have an app that has 2 views and ech one of them has the same Directive repeated a few times within it (each directive has a different content though). So the structure looks like this:

```
<view-1>
  <my-directive>
  <my-directive>
  <my-directive>
</view-1>

<view-2>
  <my-directive>
  <my-directive>
  <my-directive>
  <my-directive>
</view-2>
```

*Note, the above is not actual code.*

**The problem**
How do I launch a function **once** after one of **myDirective** has loaded/rendered (preferably after the last one has rendered)?

**My Code**

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: myDirectiveCtrl,
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link() {
        function onceFunction() {
            // Launch this once
        }

        onceFunction();
    }

    function myDirectiveCtrl() {
    }
}

angular.module('app').controller('myViewController', myViewController);

function myViewController() {
    var ctrl = this;
}
```

The above code obviously launches 3 times in view-1 and 4 times in view-2, which is not what I'm aiming for.

**Solutions I have tried**
1) Creating a service that will store a boolean variable set initially to **true** inside myViewController. Then, inside my link function (or myDirectiveCtr) create a function that will check **if** that variable is **true** if it is, set it to **false** and **launch** the function.
This works but I create a service that's only function is to communicate this true/false information.

2) Same as above but with the usage of $rootScope and probably $broadcast().

3) Using a $timeout function inside myViewController() which is a terrible sollution. ($timeout 0 does not work).

4) Some strange stuff like adding it inside the main app.js with mixed results.

**Final notes**
The function does not have to be inside any of the above controllers/link functions.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem to me: you're asking how to implement a solution to an unknown problem, but that solution has a good chance of not being the right one for the actual problem. Tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: If your asking what's inside the function then:
angular.element('#footer').addClass('ui-scrollpoint');

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking you to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well, ui-scrollpoint adds a 'ui-scrollpoint' class  that problaby gets removed once the page is rendered since the content inside the page changes it's height and height is the condition is checks too add/remove the above class. Hence when the page renders the #footer does not have the class, it is added once the page is scrolled (but that's not good enough). The solution is to add the class once the page is rendered. I'm not sure if this answers your question.